# Multiple Instances Same Context (with no control over constructors) API

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to design my first API and it looks pretty cool so far but I hit a brick wall for the last couple of days.

I have no control over the inherited constructors I'm providing via my API and I have a class that in some cases needs to be shared between multiple instances from the start.

I'm trying to avoid singletons or static properties, they don't seem clean enough.

And

Code Example:

```
public abstract class Abstract
{
    private Context context;

    private IList<Abstract> sons;

    public Abstract
    {
        if(context == null)
           context = new Context();
    }

    //this part is where it gets problematic
    internal void AddContext(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void AddSon(Abstract abstract)
    {
        abstract.AddContext(this.context);
        sons.Add(abstract);
    }   
}
```

Now user will use Abstract to inherit for his/her needs

```
public class Concrete : Abstract....
```

And initialize it at his/her discretion

```
var concrete = new Concrete();
concrete.AddSon(new Concrete());
```

without worrying to add something like

```
concrete.AddSon(new Concrete(/*same context*/)
```

if Concrete is son then Context should be shared, otherwise not. But context should be defined at constructor level.

I hope I'm explicit enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Question is how can I get multiple instances sharing an object without passing it via constructor. Keep in mind I don't want users to do any work, I don't want them to know what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: I don't understand, isn't that what you're already doing? How is the code you showed insufficient?

Comment: this is just an example code. I cant pass Abstract.Context to Concrete.Context

Comment: You need to use a Singleton in this case